# How to add fields dynamically to a form? - Implementing a django app to track order status

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

After a basic introduction to Python thanks to an edX course and a chat with a friend who told me about Django, I thought I could implement a solution for my laboratory. My goal is to keep track of every reagent order made by everyone of us researchers to the suppliers. 
After one month I have a pretty decent version of it which I'm very proud of (I also have to thank a lot of StackOverFlow questions that helped me). Nonetheless, there's one requirement of the ordering flow that I haven't been able to translate to the Django app. Let me explain:
Users have a form to anotate the reagent (one per form) they need, and then it is passed to the corresponding manufacturer for them to send us an invoice. It's convenient that each **invoice** has several products, but they all have to: **a)** be sold by the same manufacturer, **b)** be sent to the same location and **c)** be charged to the same *bank account* (it's actually more complicated, but this will suffice for the explanation).

According to that, administrators of the app could process different orders by different users and merge them together as long as they meet the three requirements.

**How would you implement this into the app regarding tables and relationships?**

What I have now is an Order Model and an Order Form which has different CharFields regarding information of the product (name, reference, etc.), and then the sending direction and the bank account (which are ForeingKeys).

When the administrators (administratives) process the orders, they asign several of them that meet the requirements to an invoice, and then the problem comes: **all the data has to be filled repeatedly for each of the orders.**

The inmediate solution for this would be to create a Products Model and then each Order instance could have various products as long as they meet the three requirements, but this presents two problems:
 1) The products table is gonna be very difficult to populate properly. Users are not gonna be concise about references and important data.
 2) We would still have different Orders that could be merged into the same invoice.

I thought maybe I could let the users add fields dynamically to the Order model (adding product 1, product 2, product 3). I read about formsets, but they repeat whole Forms as far as I understood, and I would just need to repeat fields. Anyway, that would solve the first point, but not the second.

Any suggestions?
Thanks, and sorry for the long block!

Comment: I would break the solution into as small models as possible and use a Frontend Vue architecture with Django Rest Framework in the backend for this control.
I do something similar to analyze internal processes in the company I work for, all dynamically.

Comment: Unfortunately that is far beyond my knowledge, is there anyway to stick to Python to manage this? Consider I'm just a biologist that studied a bit of Python scripting and likes tinkering with it sometimes! :P